# android fragment difference?

Tags: android, android-fragments

What is the major core difference between support library fragment and directly using android.app.Fragment.
How do they differ in performance and for future expansions and flexibility ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the support library allows you to target your app to older Android versions (API level 4 and above).

Using the support library Fragments forces your Activities to extend ActivityFragment, which can be a limit if you want your Activity to extend a different subclass of Activity.

As for performance differences, I don't know if there's a difference, but it's more likely the performance of the native fragments is better than the support library.

If you are writing an app whose only "new API" requirements are Fragments, you should probably use the support library, since many devices in the market still use pre-Android 3.0 (API level 11) versions. If you are using other new APIs, you should consider using the native Fragments of the newer APIs.